# Move constructor does not actually move my object

Tags: c++

I expect the object to be moved but it seems not. What am I doing wrong?

Result:

```cpp
addr (main) = 0x7ffe1bab6b20
addr (foo ) = 0x7ffe1bab6b00
```

Code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
 public:
  explicit Foo(std::vector<int>&& x)
      : x_(x) {}

  void myaddr() {
    std::cout << "addr (foo ) = " << &x_ << std::endl;
  }

 private:
  std::vector<int> x_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vals = {1, 2};
    std::cout << "addr (main) = " << &vals << std::endl;

    Foo foo(std::move(vals));
    foo.myaddr();
}
```

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding what "moving" means in this context. It doesn't affect addresses of objects. `x_` and `vals` are two distinct objects both in their lifetime at the same time and therefore _must_ have different addresses. Move construction or anything else can't possible change that.

Comment: "Move" doesn't move objects. It moves resources owned by those objects, so that a resource owned by one of them before, is owned by the other after. In your example, you should expect `foo.x_.data()` after the move to be equal to `vals.data()` before. Though actually, now that I look at it, `Foo` constructor doesn't actually move from `x`, but copies.

Comment: In your case the resource being moved are the elements of the vector and the allocation in which they are stored. `vals` will be an empty vector after `Foo foo(std::move(vals))` and `foo.x_` will be owning the elements and allocation instead.

Comment: I have two houses, one on 100 Main Street, and the other at 200 Main Street.  I "move" all of my stuff out of 200 Main Street, and place it at 100 Main Street.  The addresses of those houses have not changed just because I moved my stuff.  Same analogy applies here.

Comment: Or at least what my last comment said would be the case if you implemented it correctly, but currently you are missing a `std::move` in the initializer: `: x_(std::move(x)) {}` Otherwise this will still copy.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GeG1ea7hh). This fixes the example to a) actually move (your code didn't), and b) to compare the right pointers.

Comment: Thanks for all the kind comments above.

Comment: @igor Related question: if I remove && from the constructor (using your demo), it still moves properly. What's best practice?

Comment: There are two schools of thought on sink parameters.  School A) use `&&` to force the caller to explicitly `std::move` or explicitly copy their lvalue argument, rvalue silently moves as expected.  School B) use pass-by-value for sink parameters, which silently moves (for rvalues) or copies (for lvalues) the caller's argument.  (Either case, need to `std::move` the parameter into the member variable.)

Comment: The output shows that it did move. It moved from 0x7ffe1bab6b20 (`vals`) to 0x7ffe1bab6b00 (`foo.x_`).

Comment: The main difference is that, with `&&`, `Foo foo(vals);` wouldn't compile, Without `&&`, it would compile, and would result in `vals` getting copied into `foo.x_` (to be precise, `vals` is copied into the function parameter, which is them moved into `foo.x_`). You decide which semantics you prefer for your design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood `std::move`, it doesn't actually move anything it just produces a rvalue reference which enables move semantics.
after using `std::move` you `std::vector` is still in the same memory location. when you are printing the `&x` and `&vals` since they are two different object they are in different memory location.

I think this code can help you understand better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(std::vector<int>&& x) : x_(x) {}

    void myaddr() { std::cout << "addr (foo ) = " << &x_ << std::endl; }
    void addFirst() { std::cout << "addr first (foo) = " << &x_[0] << std::endl; }

private:
    std::vector<int> x_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vals = {1, 2};
    std::cout << "addr (main) = " << &vals << std::endl;
    std::cout << "addr first (main) = " <<  &vals[0] << std::endl;
    Foo foo(std::move(vals));
    foo.myaddr();
    foo.addFirst();
}
```

Result:

```
addr (main) = 0x5ffe50
addr first (main) = 0x6249e0
addr (foo) = 0x5ffe30
addr first (foo) = 0x624a20
```